# How would I reallocate a 2-dimensional array in C?

Tags: c

I'm doing a C programming assignment in which I read in the number of columns and rows from the user and make a 2D array based on the inputs given and fill in the entries with random values. How would I delete a certain column in my 2D array based on the user input (for example if the user wanted to delete the first column, how would I reallocate the matrix space?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double **initializeRandomMatrixPtr(double **a, int rows, int cols) {
    a = malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        *(a + i) = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            *(*(a + i) + j) = rand();
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void printMatrix(double **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void freeMatrix(double **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int main(void) {
    int rows = -1;
    int cols = -1;
    int deletedColumn = -1;
    // remove first column
    printf("Enter number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter number of cols:");
    scanf("%d", &cols);
    double **matrix = initializeRandomMatrixPtr(matrix, rows, cols);
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    freeMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    printf("What column do you want to delete?");
    scanf("%d", deletedColumn);
    realloc(matrix, ) // what should I put for my second parameter?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ for a C question unless you want to read "Why are you not using `std::string`/`std::vector`?" over and over again.

Comment: my instructor doesn't allow the use of std::vector or std:: string.

Comment: Since you already have a jagged array allocated, you just call free on the pointer in your outer matrix pointer and set it to NULL so that you know it is free.  Instead of thinking of your matrix as a 2D array, think of it as an array of arrays - since this is how you have allocated it anyway.

Comment: j.doe If you have other restrictions akin to  "doesn't allow the use of std::vector or std:: string", put them in the question.

Comment: Look at your `freeMatrix()` - instead of calling free on every entry, call it on just one.

Comment: @chux, the question is tagged `c` now, so std::vector no longer applies.

Comment: Now if you need to fill in the "gap" created by this, then it gets a bit more interesting as you then must copy everything down a slot inside your outer array iinto the gap the free created and then possibly realloc the outside array 1 entry smaller.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The recommendation still applies for OP to list any restrictions in the question.

Comment: Second parameter to `realloc` is the new size. Don't be horrified if you get the same address returned after a `realloc`. Sometimes the runtime gives you more than you need (because that was the most available block at least the size asked for) so you can grow without actually reallocating anything.

Comment: do you have to use an array of pointers? it's more complicated than a flat array

Comment: You can pass `matrix` as the first parameter to `realloc` if and only if you are increasing the number of rows in the matrix. Decreasing the number of rows with a single call to `realloc` will result in a memory leak. Changing the number of columns is simply not possible when using `matrix` as the first parameter to `realloc`.

Comment: You can call realloc when decreasing the matrix, but only after freeing the internal malloc and then filling in the space that the free caused with a memory move of some sort.

Comment: It is useless and error prone to pass `matrix` to `initializeRandomMatrixPtr(matrix, rows, cols);`

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I'm not going to actually post any code:

To reallocate your array of arrays 1 entry (one whole row or column) smaller:

1. Go into your outer array to the index/entry to be deleted and call free() on that pointer.  This will free all data associated with that row/column/list.
2. If you are expected to keep the array contiguous (you probably are), you need to either call memmove (not memcpy), or use for loop copy the pointers in the outer loop from 1 past the delete entry to the end of the outer loop into the gap created by the deleted entry.
3. Finally, you then need to call realloc on the outer array, decreasing the needed size by 1 pointer.

You will also probably need to track the state of this array by storing at least the number of entries in your outer array of pointers to pointers - to prevent you from reading past the end of the newly sized list when it comes time to print the size again or resize it or whatever.

In case you are trying to remove entries in the other direction (1 entry per allocation from the outer loop), the process is similar:

Visit each entry in the outer loop and do the following:

1. Call memmove() or for loop copy from 1 beyond the entry to delete to the entry (beware not to read past end of array).
2. call realloc() on that entry with the new, 1 smaller size.

Comment: This accurately describes how to delete a row from the matrix. But the OP asks *"How would I delete a certain **column** ..."*

Comment: `*(a + i) = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));` as the inside alloc seems to indicate that rows are in the outside of the loop and columns are the inner loop.  I will describe the other method too though, just in case.  Honestly, it's almost the same process.

Comment: To be honest, the best way to delete the column is to not delete it at all. Move everything after the column in question over one slot and pretend you deleted it.

Comment: `*(a + i) = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));` allocates memory for one row, that has space for N `double` values, where N is equal to `cols`.

Comment: Either way - I add the process for the other way too.  And yes!  Not reallocating smaller is simpler and internally the realloc is probably doing just this...